# How to convert xfa pdf file to normal pdf file that can be open in browser

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfbox, itext7

I have filled xfa pdf form and i want to convert this pdf into normal pdf that can be open in browser.
I´m searching free open source .

I have used pdfbox 2.0 it will flatten pdf but not convert in normal pdf

```
  try
    {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new java.io.File(sourcePdfPath));

        PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        
        pdAcroForm.flatten();

        doc.save(destinationPdfPath);
        doc.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

I have used itext but itext need licence so dont know about itext will convert or not.

Comment: "XFA PDFs" **are** "normal PDFs" because they're incorporated into the PDF 1.5 specification - the problem is that Chromium and Firefox's specific PDF readers don't support XFA.

Comment: @Dai can we convert xfa pdf into pdf that can be open in browser

Comment: with iText, you need a license to use [pdfXFA](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdfxfa) to _flatten_ the PDF XFA into a "regular" PDF file. I don't think there are any free or opensource alternatives.

Comment: @Dai *"XFA PDFs" are "normal PDFs"* - well, meanwhile (since the publication of ISO 32000-2 in 2017) the use of xfa in pdfs is deprecated, so xfa pdfs nowadays are *not* normal but obsolete.